# Elastic search - No node attributes configured in elasticsearch.yml You can't control shard allocation without node attributes

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

When setting up index cold/warm phases in Kibana, this error appears:

```
No node attributes configured in elasticsearch.yml
You can't control shard allocation without node attributes.

Learn about shard allocation. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/shards-allocation.html
```

I have added the shard allocation configuration (detailed in the above link) to elasticsearch.yml on all 3 nodes, but still get the same error. What am I missing?

```
#SHARD ALLOCATION

cluster.routing.allocation.enable: All
cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_incoming_recoveries: 2
cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_outgoing_recoveries: 2
cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_recoveries: 2
cluster.routing.allocation.node_initial_primaries_recoveries: 4
cluster.routing.allocation.same_shard.host: false

#SHARD BALANCING

cluster.routing.rebalance.enable: all
cluster.routing.allocation.allow_rebalance: indices_all_active
cluster.routing.allocation.cluster_concurrent_rebalance: 2
cluster.routing.allocation.balance.shard: 0.45f
cluster.routing.allocation.balance.index: 0.55f
cluster.routing.allocation.balance.threshold: 1.0f

#DISK SPACE MANAGEMENT

cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: true
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low: 85%
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high: 90%
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage: 95%
cluster.info.update.interval: 240s
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.include_relocations: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a node attribute, you should add a setting like:

```
node.attr.[some attribute]: value
```

like

```
node.attr.box_type: hot
```

and later you can change an index setting and make it to be on a so cold hot node:

```
PUT /logs_2016-12-26
{
  "settings": {
    "index.routing.allocation.require.box_type": "hot"
  }
}
```

`box_type` is an arbitrary attribute here.

For more details you can check [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/hot-warm-architecture-in-elasticsearch-5-x) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html)

Comment: Thanks for that. Didn't realise that the nodes needed to be specifically named hot or cold.

Comment: strangely once I added the attributes to the nodes, the error message disappeared and there was an option not to use them